# Mixing tenses in sentences

Tags: tenses

Which of the following sound more appropriate?

1. The projects that I have worked on are .....
2. The projects that I have worked on were....
3. The projects had funding, which is either x type or y type.
4. The projects had funding, which was either x type or y type.

Please provide me with any reading materials on this topic if possible.

Comment: Does [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/118118/395547) help?

Comment: 1. is in the present perfect tense and will be appropriate if what follows links to the present - e.g. The projects that I have worked on are still active (now). 2. It is hard to see how following the present perfect tense with "were" can lead to a connection to the present - maybe ... were all still active last time I enquired"? 3. does not sound right to me - even if the funding type is still extant. 4. all good. Sorry - no reading materials - all from the top of my head.